# How to call function of statefulwidget in stateless?

Tags: flutter

I have a piechart in the body of my scaffold in the homepage. The MyPieChart is a statefulWidget, it has a bool variable toggle. I made it so that when toggle is false the build returns a text "Testing" and when toggle is true the build returns the actual PieChart. How can i change toggle from the onPressed of floating action button inside my homepage. Here's the code of my Homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing/MyPieChart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stateful Chart',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, double> dataMap = new Map();
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Flutter", () => 5);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("React", () => 3);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Xamarin", () => 2);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Ionic", () => 2);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PieChart"),
      ),
      body: MyPieChart(dataMap),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {}
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways. You can use keys, any StateManagement like ScopedModel, etc. Just search for them. Key would be the simplest solution in your case.

Comment: Move the toggle state up into the `HomePage` making it stateful. See the linked answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - notify sibling widgets inside Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543070/flutter-notify-sibling-widgets-inside-column)